# SVN Accidently del trunk and not committed change

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, trunk, svn-trunk

How do you fix this scenario? So basically I am in PROD/WHOTest file and typed svn del trunk

Have not committed changes yet. How do you back out?

svn del --keep local trunk
or 
svn revert trunk

Answer (score 2):

`svn revert .` should do the trick. With TortoiseSVN, select the directory which contained trunk, and revert.

`svn del --keep-local` is used to delete a file or folder in SVN, but keeping the file or folder in the working copy.